# "Lock obtain timed out exception" with no "write.lock" file

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am getting `Lock obtain timed out` exception with entirely empty index folder.

This exception throws at the moment I try to create an index with following code:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)
```

How could I possibly solve this error?

Comment: was the directory created by the same user as the process trying to open it?

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible causes:

1. Your directory does not have sufficient access. To fix this, right click on the directory>properties>security>make sure your process IIS_IUSRS has privileges
2. Another process is using the directory at the same time. Use Lock Hunter to detect which process is using this file
3. The write.lock in the directory is an orphan file, initially it was created but due to the process being killed, it has stayed there.
4. You are not Optimizing/Commiting/Disposing the writer which you have opened

To commit/dispose writer:

```
writer.Optimize();
writer.Commit();
writer.Dispose();
```

I had this issue then had an instance of IProviderContext which was not being optimized/commited/disposed.

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Stopping the web server, deleting the index folder and restarting solved the issue for me.